# Can you see the fault? Why json decode return NULL?

Tags: php, json

everyone. I would like to know your opinion about a strange event for me. So can you find in the following code, why the first json_decode return NULL, but the second is fine..

```
$json = '{"Peter":65,"Harry":80,"John":78,"Clark":90}';
$output = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($ouput);

$second_json = '{"Peter":65,"Harry":80,"John":78,"Clark":90}';
$output = json_decode($second_json);
var_dump($output);
```

And the response is

```
  NULL object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["Peter"]=> int(65) ["Harry"]=> int(80) ["John"]=> int(78) ["Clark"]=> int(90) }
```

Thx for your time, I am looking forward for your answers

Comment: there is an online json validator, that tells you if the json syntax is OK: https://jsonlint.com/. If that validates your strings as OK then well most probably a typo(as it was already pointed out)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Correct your `$output` variable in third line then try again. In my computer there is not a problem with your code.

```
<?php
$json = '{"Peter":65,"Harry":80,"John":78,"Clark":90}';
$output = json_decode($json,true);
var_dump($output);

$second_json = '{"Peter":65,"Harry":80,"John":78,"Clark":90}';
$output = json_decode($second_json);
var_dump($output);
```

**output:**

```
array(4) { ["Peter"]=> int(65) ["Harry"]=> int(80) ["John"]=> int(78) ["Clark"]=> int(90) } object(stdClass)#1 (4) { ["Peter"]=> int(65) ["Harry"]=> int(80) ["John"]=> int(78) ["Clark"]=> int(90) }
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and full detail answer. Have a nice day

Answer (score 3):

`var_dump($output);` instead of `var_dump($ouput);`

Comment: You have right! Always i am making these sillies mistake. Thx for your response. Have a nice day